# Compiling complex Python project

Tags: python, compilation

I have a somewhat complex Python project.
The structure looks like:

```
    main_project/
        my_scripts/
            function1.py
            function2.py
        lib/
            library1.py
            library2.py
        main_program.py
```

main_program.py imports function1.py and function2.py as well as the files in lib/. The scripts in my_scripts/ also import the files in lib/. function1.py and function2.py can be used directly from the command line and passed arguments that way, or imported as modules, like in main_program.py. The code by itself is working perfectly in Python.

I want to compile the project to a binary format (for example using Py2exe, pyinstaller, Nuitka, etc.) However, want function1.py and function2.py to remain both executables and modules, and not just have main_program.py compiled with its dependencies.

I tried many programs and I'm encountering either import problems, compilation problems, or general problems with using the Python compiler.

Can someone indicate a simple way to compile the different files into executables without having to include the dependencies into each binary file I want?

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, you could just combine function1 and function2 into one function program, then compile that together. If that doesn't work, just try and import the source code of the functions into the main file, and make them separate functions.

Comment: @user1283, could you please be more specific about your problem and is your code running at all (before trying to compile/build) ?

Comment: @MauriceMeyer I forgot to mention it, but my code is working fine by itself. The issue is that I can't find a way to compile the different scripts in a reasonable way. The best method I found was to use pyinstaller to gather ALL the dependencies (some of which are shared in between scripts) and pack them into every executable. Thanks for your question :)

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by "callable by themselves"?  A .py file is not a "callable" because it's not a function - it's a module.  The file is therefore "importable" but it's not "callable."  It may contain callables, but before they can be called the module must be imported into the running environment.  All .py files are importable, but your environment must be set up in such a way that it can find the files it needs to import.  py2exe puts files inside a .zip file, and can make multiple executables that share the same .zip file.  Is that what you want to do?

Comment: function1.py and function2.py both have shebangs and a main function. The scripts can be used directly from the command line and passed arguments that way, or imported as modules and used that way. (I'll edit the question)

I would like to preserve this option while compiling the package without having to include duplicated data in every executable. So yes, I guess I want to make multiple executables that share the same .zip file like you say!

Comment: Is your desired result to have 3 executables ? main_program.exe, function1.exe and function2.exe ?

Comment: Yes, exactly :)